# How to correct phase using arctangent as Phase Detector

Tags: phase, pll

I have a DPLL that's trying to lock to a DSB-SC input signal with a carrier whose phase is $\theta$. So after some mixing and filtering (Costas Loop), I have these two signals ($\hat{\theta}$ is the estimated phase by the DPLL):

$$
s_I(t) = 0.5x(t)cos(\theta-\hat{\theta})
$$
$$
s_Q(t) = 0.5x(t)sin(\theta-\hat{\theta})
$$

And the output of my phase detector is:
$$
q(t)=atan\left(\frac{s_I(t)}{s_Q(t)}\right)=atan\left(\frac{sin(\theta-\hat{\theta})}{cos(\theta-\hat{\theta})}\right)=atan(tan(\theta-\hat{\theta}))
$$

But as you know, $atan(tan(\theta-\hat{\theta}))=\theta-\hat{\theta}$ only if $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq(\theta-\hat{\theta})\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I know how I could adjust $\theta-\hat{\theta}$ so that they fall within the accepted range. The thing is, I don't have access to $\theta-\hat{\theta}$ but to $s_I(t)$ and $s_Q(t)$.

What could be done to guarantee there's no phase ambiguity? I mean, I can adjust only $\hat{\theta}$ since I'm generating it, but adjusting that one doesn't mean that $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq(\theta-\hat{\theta})\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ will be true.

Comment: You. don't want to use the $\arctan$ function in determining the phase but rather the [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function which gives a value between $-\pi$ and $+\pi$.

Comment: That’s true, I found out about it after writing the post but I would still have the same problem, I’d still need to make sure $-\pi\leq(\theta-\hat{\theta})\leq\pi$, so how could I achieve it?

Comment: Pass $\left(\frac{s_Q(t)}{\sqrt{s_I^2(t) +s_Q^2(t)}}, \frac{s_I(t)}{\sqrt{s_I^2(t) +s_Q^2(t)}}\right)$ as arguments to `atan2` and you will get the value of $\theta -\hat\theta$ which is guaranteed to lie in $[-\pi,\pi]$,

Comment: The phase ambiguity is a real problem that defines the lock range of your DPLL in terms of maximum frequency offset otherwise you can lock to an alias location; often a frequency lock loop is also used to ensure your frequency is within this proper capture range so that you do not get a false lock; or there is an initial frequency search during acquisition prior to the final pull-in of your DPLL. Also, typically the resources to compute an ATAN2 are not necessary in practical implementations as you can sufficiently approximate the phase such as using the cross-product phase detector

Comment: (See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31497/how-to-correct-the-phase-offset-for-qpsk-i-q-data/31506#31506)

Comment: Hmm, now that you mention it, I'm comparing the output of the DPLL to the carrier and it looks like it's locked but I'm getting an error phase that's not equal to zero. Might that be because of the false lock you mention? So I'd just need to use an FLL? Also thanks for the approximation, I'll take a look